# What should be the port value for working on the production server?

Tags: python, django, google-api-python-client

When developing on a local machine I used standart code to authorize and work with Google disk

```
creds = None
cred = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'credentials.json')
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            cred, SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

I use 8080 as the port parameter value. This works. When deploying a project on a production server, I get a message `port is already in use`.

Server: Ubuntu 18.04, Nginx, uwsgi

What values should I use?

**UPD**

I've changed the port to 5000, everything works on the local machine. I tried to run it on a production server and got a 504 error. I checked the uwsgi log and saw that the end of the file contains a link to authorization. 
[image]
On the local machine, this link automatically opens in a new window to log on to the account. If try to run the production server again, I will get the **[Errno 98] Address already in use error** and this error is saved until  reboot uwsgi. After the reboot, everything repeats itself again.

Comment: In production you will use some `wsgi` server to mediate between the `nginx/apache` server with your app. And the server(apache/nginx) will then be running and processing requests on 80/443 obviously :)

Comment: @hansolo Does this mean I need to use the value of port 80?

Comment: You can use any port if it doesn't conflict with any other services. Default port for nginx is 80, but you can specify it in nginx conf file your application, just make sure the same port is specified in your django

Comment: I try 8079 and 8081, but result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Try netstat to see what ports are in use.

> netstat -an | grep LISTEN
>
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Any of the ports returned will give you the error 'port is already in use' above.
Any other port should work.
It is better to use port above 1024 and an unprivileged user for security reasons. Port 8000 or port 8888 are often used by django, but any port can be used.

You could also use a socket.

Ports 8078, 8079 and 8080 are generally used by applications server like tomcat / jetty.

Comment: I've tried many different port meanings, the same problem with everyone. I think the problem here is not in the specific meaning. After restart uwsgi there is an attempt of authorization (i.e. the value of the port is accepted) but the redirection by reference to OAuth2 does not occur. And it's quite strange that when  try again, the error  `[Errno 98] Address already in use`

Comment: `sudo systemctl start uwsgi`

Comment: I have a  systemd unit file to manage the uWSGI emperor process and automatically start uWSGI at boot

Comment: I added my uwsgi.service config to question

Comment: It looks like you need to change port 8080 to a port that is not in use.  If you runnetstat, it will give a list of ports you are LISTENING to - these would all give an error.  Any other port should work.